# Should I store my data in a Sharedpreference in my fragments or in a activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewpager with two fragments. In both fragments I have three edittexts. When the user presses a button, I want to store the text in the 6 (3x2) edittexts using sharedpreferences. Should I in both fragments open sharedpreferences and store the text, or should i parse the text from the edittexts to the activity where the viewpager is in, and open the sharedpreferences in the activity and store the data there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a personal opinion if you want to store all values in the same `SharedPreferences` file just do it in the `Activity` and communicate from the `Fragment`'s to your `Activity` using an `interface` so you are reading & writing data to the preference file in one place.

If you are using different `SharedPreferences` file names then it is really up to you, but if only each one of the `Fragment`'s will be editing their distinct file then why put the code for saving and reading anywhere else but for those `Fragments`.

Again, there is no wrong way to do this either one will work because `SharedPreferences` files are stored for your application globally not for the `Activity` or `Fragment` currently on the stack so it really depends on how organized you want to be.